# Calculating cross-correlation between 2 signals using FFT without considering lags

Tags: numpy, scipy, fft, cross-correlation

I'm trying to calculate the cross correlation between 2 signals without considering a lag. Essentially I want to recreate the cross correlation of 2 signals with zero lags, to see if my understanding of how cross correlation is calculated is correct.

The following is my code:

```
x1 = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,1000)
y1 = np.sin(x1)
#second signal is with a phase shift of pi/4
y2 = np.sin(x1 - np.pi/4)

#do FFT on each signal
y1_fft = np.fft.fft(y1)
y2_fft = np.fft.fft(y2)

#complex conjugate of y2_fft
y2_conj = np.conjugate(y2_fft)

#take inner product of the fft and conjugate of fft
np.inner(y1_fft,y2_conj)
```

The result is `-353199.837 - 2.59E-11i` which is wrong

In comparison when I use `scipy.signal.correlate` the following is the result

```
corr = sg.correlate(y1,y2,method='fft')
lags = sg.correlation_lags(y1.shape[0],y2.shape[0])
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize = (10,10))
ax.plot(lags,corr)
```

[image: Cross Correlation with lags]

As seen, the cross-correlation at zero lag is around 475, however my result is very different.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The unnormalized circular correlation is calculated as follows

```
# your code
import numpy as np
x1 = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,1000)
y1 = np.sin(x1)
y2 = np.sin(x1 - np.pi/4)
y1_fft = np.fft.fft(y1)
y2_fft = np.fft.fft(y2)
y2_conj = np.conjugate(y2_fft)

# calculate the correlation (without padding)
corr = np.fft.ifft(y1_fft * y2_conj)
np.sum(y1*y2), corr[0]
```

by circular correlation I mean that the signal will be rolled instead of shifted, rolling or shifting are equivalent for `lag[0]`, but for e.g. lag=3 you would get something like

```py
np.sum(y1*np.roll(y2, 3)), corr[3]
```

not the same as

```py
np.sum(y1[3:] * y2[:-3])
```

If you want only correlation with lag 0, to be honest I think it is better to compute by the definition directly `np.inner(y1, y2)`.